# Sqlite3 recover runs into out of memory error

Tags: database, sqlite, recovery

I'm trying to recover a broken sqlite database using the recover feature of sqlite3.exe:

```
sqlite3.exe borken.db ".recover" | sqlite3 fixed.db
```

The broken database has a size of 142 mb. When running the command I'll get the following error after a while:

```
SQL error: out of memory
```

Is there a known workaround for this issue?

The process doesn't seem to need a lot of value so it doesn't seem to be the real error reason.

I've also tried the x64 version of sqlite3.exe which uses a max of around 6 mb memory. So it doesn't seem to be a real memory issue.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your command structure, I'm going to assume you're on a Linux OS.

You can use the rqlite utility if you first dump the database file to a backup. Process would look like this:

1. Open the database file in sqlite and run .output /path/to dump/file.dump
2. Once the database is dumped, install the rqlite utility [here](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite/releases)
3. Once rqlite is installed, you can run it in memory if your database is less than
   2gb in total size on disk. If it's larger, you need to mount a ramdisk so that the
   resulting run database can be stored to disk rather than caching it in memory.
   Sequence of commands would look something like this:

   sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=3072m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk # Set size to be less than
   the available memory on disk

   ./rqlited -on-disk -on-disk-startup -on-disk-path /mnt/ramdisk/node1/db.sqlite
   /path/to/data/dir

I recommned running the above in a separate screen session. Then you can go in a separate instance/session and run rqlite as follows:

```
./rqlite
.restore /path/to/dumped/database/file.dump
```

Additional great documentation and examples about it [here](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite/blob/master/DOC/PERFORMANCE.md#in-memory-database-limits)