# I'm trying to recover a malformed database using '.recover' command but I get an 'out of memory' error (OOM)

Tags: database, sqlite, recover

I am trying to recover a database of not more than 23 MB containing around 6 months of fitness related data. I transferred the file online from my phone to my laptop using Filezilla app (ASCII method) which added some bytes to the file causing it to corrupt. That is my hunch.

I am not able to open it in DB Browser for SQLite. Error - 'Could not open database file. Reason: database disk is malformed'.

.dump command from CLI:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/****** CORRUPTION ERROR *******/
/****** database disk image is malformed ******/
/****** ERROR: database disk image is malformed ******/
/****** CORRUPTION ERROR *******/
/****** database disk image is malformed ******/
/****** ERROR: database disk image is malformed ******/
/**** ERROR: (11) database disk image is malformed *****/
COMMIT;
```

[How to recover a corrupt SQLite3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database/57872238#57872238)

[Sqlite3 recover runs into out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178203/sqlite3-recover-runs-into-out-of-memory-error)

I followed the suggestions given above but mostly ended with a blank db or sql file.

Then I tried the '.recover' method. It ran for a few seconds and gave the out of memory error. I need to bypass the OOM issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to transfer the DB file in binary mode?

Comment: No. I didnt have access to it as I formatted the phone thinking I had backed up a good copy.

Comment: And your target system is windows? Please check: https://superuser.com/questions/195612/recovering-corrupted-files-uploaded-in-wrong-ftp-mode

Comment: I transferred the file from Android to Mac using Filezilla. Corruption of data due to additional bytes could just be my hunch. What I really want is a method to run the .recover command on Mac/Windows/Linux without running into OOM isssue.

Comment: Which MAC OS Version? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/18667225

Comment: MacOS Catalina. Currently on 10.15.7.